# PHP/MySQL Timezone when working only with Date not Time

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

My question is more on the concept side.

I'm wondering how to deal with dates only based information. For example, when you have a day to take a vacation or something like that on February 24th and you store on the database as 2015-02-24 00:00:00 right.... how do I deal with conversions in this case?

I already now how to convert timezones, it works with no problem in cases where the user selects a time too. But when I use 00:00:00 in cases only the date matters I'm having problems to figure it out.

For example:
Let's say I setup my vacation to be on the 24th of February and I'm on EST right, and the system is saving all times on EST. It will convert and it will be saved as 2015-02-24 00:00:00

Then somebody on PST time will check it out, and when it convert to them it will be 2015-02-23 21:00:00 ... and it will show my vacation in their point of you it will be on the 23rd.

Is that a correct logic? How should I save on the database the time in that case? Keep it as 00:00:00?

I hope I was able to explain myself.

Thanks

Comment: do you want it to show up correctly if someone in Europe says they'll be on vacation on the 24th? in PST the correct date for that would be the 23rd to not mess anything up, if you don't care much for that, then just don't convert the date and display it

Comment: Hi @iam-decoder thanks for participating. Yes, I want to be able to show correct day on other people timezone, as in your example the PST would be different. Is that possible?

Comment: you just need to come up with a time you'd consider a cutoff, for my employee screens I have it set up that if someone in Europe were to request a vacation it stores as `2015-08-18 00:00:00` when the timezone converts it to PST, roughly `2015-08-17 18:00:00`, if the time is on or after 19:00:00 (end of work day) it will round the date up to `2015-08-18`, otherwise it'll keep the converted date of `2015-08-17`

Comment: Hi @iam-decoder, that's a good idea. How it would work in the case if someone on the PST side edit the vacation day to the 19th for example?

Comment: just keep the original time zone and keep note if the date was rounded down, before saving do the reverse calculation.

Comment: @iam-decoder Ok, what if like this, let me know if would work. I'm in Europe, I select the 18th, it would then calculate the base time (it can be EST, or GMT it doesn't matter) of the date that was insert. For example... normally it would be 2015-02-18 00:00:00 but what if I transform it and store based on the base timezone (let's say EST to make it easier)... it would be 2015-02-17 21:00:00... then if it's read by the Europe, it would be 2015-02-18 00:00:00.. and if it's read by the PST it would be 2015-02-17 18:00:00 ... would that be confusing?

Comment: Hi @iam-decoder could you post your idea as an answer so I can accept it? Could you also add a small sample structure of the database with an example of back and forth? Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can save the date in unix timestamp in the database (always save the current time in GMT even if you are in EST).

And when displaying the date, convert it to the user's timezone.

Comment: Yes, but even saving in unix timestamp, GMT, what would be the logic used in case of only a date not time being used? What date would you store (translated to english, I know you 're using gmt unix timestamp) and use to convert? Could you give examples, of back and forth between a PST and a Europe time for example? Thanks!